# c# Pow/Datatype Conversion

Tags: c#, .net

I'm fairly new to programming in general. I have read through a raft of posts regarding casting datatype when using the POW function and have tried to take note.

I can't understand why the following isn't working. In the debugger y is getting assigned to 0. I can't understand why this is. I think it is something to do with how I am converting Doubles/Decimals?

```
 public decimal MonthsPayment(){
            decimal monthlyint = this.Rate / 12;
            int totalpayments = this.Term * 12;
            decimal x = monthlyint * this.Amount;

            decimal s1 = (1+monthlyint);
            decimal s2 = (-totalpayments);

            decimal y = (decimal)(Math.Pow((double)s1,(double)s2));
            decimal Repayment = x /(1 - y);
            return Repayment;
```

Comment: Look at the values of `monthlyint` (especially) and 'totalpayments` in the debugger. Depending on the types of `Rate` and `Term`, you may be experiencing integer truncation.

Comment: What is type of `Rate` and `Term` ? dont forget (1/12 is 0 (*integer division*))

Comment: Also, check your math. What does `y` mean? If `Term` is 5 for example, then `totalpayments` is 60. On the line you're calculating `y`, pretty much anything to the `-60` power is pretty close to zero.

Comment: If the output of Pow is unexpected then **the inputs must be wrong**.  You're running a debugger; what are the values of s1 and s2? Is one of them unexpected? If so, well, now you've reduced your problem to a smaller problem. Keep doing that until you find the problem.

Comment: Also, you will help yourself and others by breaking yourself of the habit of using "x" and "y" and "s1" and "s2" as variable names immediately. You're off to a great start with names like "totalpayment" -- though you should use camelCaseIdentifiers -- but we have no intuition whatsoever about what a correct value should be for x or y.

Comment: @BobKaufman: I'm pretty sure the OP intended to say `1.0/totalPayments`. But what's more important than finding the specific mistake here is to get in the habit of using a debugger and other good practices to find this sort of problem without external assistance.

Comment: Incidentally, good on you for using decimals to represent financial quantities. Using doubles to represent money is a common error.

Comment: Hi all, thank you for the comments, wasn't expecting such quick responses! this is for a Mortgage Calc program im making to try and get into OO programming. 

The Repayment return value is based on the calculation: P  = x / (1 - (1 + i)^-N) Rate is a member variable of my class and is a decimal. Term is an int.

In the debugger s1 = 1.2616666 and s2 = -360 So on second glance it is looking like a math error1

Comment: Guys, I think I'm almost there, quite embarrassing really - the interest rate I was entering was 3.14 (314%) when it should have been /100 to make 0.0314. I will take on board comments regarding variable naming/types (I've managed to confuse myself with something this simple so i think it will pay off to write code I can understand when I come back to it)

Comment: That definitely pays dividends. So to speak. Glad you figured out your problem.